# Remove phone number from iMessage?

Tags: messages

Friend of mine got a new phone number that came linked to an iMessage account. He can’t see text messages (iMessages) sent from iPhones because the account is linked to the phone and iPhones send the messages to the account by default. He doesn’t have access to the Apple ID nor does he have an iPhone.

How would he unlink the account? Apple conviently doesn’t list this information anywhere.